# Aurora3 RDS MySQL Stored function/trigger performance when using information_schema

Tags: stored-procedures, trigger, amazon-rds, information-schema, aurora

Since moving to Aurora3 RDS (MySQL 8 based) vs Aurora 2 (MySQL 5.7 based) noticed that execution time of certain triggers and stored functions performance has degraded. Correlation between triggers and functions was the select query on information_schema.table something like

```
SELECT `AUTO_INCREMENT` FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = DATABASE() AND table_name LIKE tablename LIMIT 1
```

RDS Stack has 50+ schemas with close to 2000+ tables in each. Can take > 25s (unloaded system, no other users/connections). Query above run outside of stored function/trigger takes < 0.1s (same as it did in 5.7 stored/trigger).

Performs best when single database stack. Can also get better performance by changing the definer of the function/trigger to be schema based user. Unable to reproduce locally on Community Edition of MySQL8.